# Sequence of functions applied to a string in functional style

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I am trying to understand the ways of using functional style in JavaScript in practice. I've created a simple set of functions to process a string, but I feel I am doing it conceptually wrong because it looks just like imperative style, even though I don't mutate input and don't change state of the app inside the functions.

Here is how it looks:

```
var LineParser = require('../modules/LineParser');
var inputLine = 'A line with     multiple          spaces';
var outputLine = LineParser().formatSpaces(inputLine);
//  'A line with multiple spaces'
outputLine = LineParser().capitalize(outputLine);
//  'A Line With Multiple Spaces'
outputLine = LineParser().formatSomethingElse(outputLine);
//  Some more formatting, then do further processing with outputLine
```

If I run the sequence using callbacks, it is going to become an ugly set of nested callbacks really quickly when I have, say, 10 simple processing functions.

If I add methods chaining, the idea of prototype methods looks against functional style too, because functions in the chain will depend on previous state, not only on the input they get.

What should I do to make it look nicer in a functional style?

**Update:** After deeper research I found topic named [Function Composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition_(computer_science)). It seems to be a proper solution to the problem and is one of the basic things from the functional world.
Here is the function I use to compose multiple functions into one:

```
var compose = function () {
    var funcs = arguments;
    return function () {
        var args = arguments;
        for (var i = funcs.length; i-- > 0;) {
            args = [funcs[i].apply(this, args)];
        }
        return args[0];
    };
};
```

Then I do a composition:

```
var composedFunction = compose(func1, func2, ..., funcn)
```

Which run from the right to left and all works just fine.

Comment: What do you mean by "*If I run the sequence using callbacks*"? Why would you do that? Are your string functions asynchronous?

Comment: I don't see why prototype methods would be against the functional style. As methods, they might get their first argument (the object) in a unconventional syntax, but they are just functions as well. They work especially way with immutable objects.

Comment: Why is `LineParser` a function, why do you need to call it, what does it do?

Comment: By callbacks I mean passing functions as arguments to other functions, may be using wrong terminology in context of functional programming, just like `formatSomethingElse(formatSpaces(inputLine));`.

`LineParser` is just a function returning other functions, can be turned into an object containing functions.

Comment: Yes, that's wrong terminology (and maybe wrong understanding). The argument to your outer function call is itself created by evaluating function *call* - but you're still passing a string, not a function, so no callbacks here. Actually I think that approach is rather standard in functional programming, not getting ugly :-)

Answer (score 0):

You lineparser seems to have methods like `formatSpaces`, `capitalize` and `formatSomethingElse`. The easiest thing you could do is to make all those methods to `return this`, so that you can chain those methods like so:

```
var outputline = LineParser.formatSpaces(inputLine).capitalize().formatSomethingElse()
```

Though by the looks of it, all of the methods require some string as a parameter, so you might have to make some implementation changes such as saving the string in a private variable if given and pullin it from the variable if no parameters are given.

Comment: I tried it, but it seems to be against functional style because of relying on previous app state.

Comment: @SergeiBasharov Maybe you could explore how something like http://functionaljs.com/ works? "Functional" in JavaScript usually means utilizing `map`, `reduce` and `filter` instead of looping though arrays for example.

Comment: @SergeiBasharov Oh and this lineparser of yours might not be the best idea if you want to learn functional JavaScript. If I were you I would probably just learn how some functional libraries are made.

Answer (score 0):

Remark about your Edit. The function `compose` is very functional in the principle but not in its implementation. Indeed, the function mutates some variables (e.g., `i` and  `args`) and is therefore not fully functional.

To avoid using these mutating variables, you could possibly define `compose` recursively. Another solution ould be to rely on third-party functional library, such as underscore-js for example (http://underscorejs.org/), which already defines a composition function.

Additional (obvious) remark: to make your code functional with compose, the functions `func1`, `func2`,... that are composed, should not mutate their arguments.

Answer (score -1):

If you want asynchronous programming but you don't like nested callbacks, have you considered the [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) lib ?
You could have something like this :

```
var LineParser = require('../modules/LineParser');
var inputLine = 'A line with     multiple          spaces';

async.waterfall([
    function(callback) {
        var result = LineParser().formatSpaces(inputLine);
        callback(null, result);
    },
    function(arg1, callback) {
        var result = LineParser().capitalize(arg1);
        callback(null, result);
    },
    function(arg1, callback) {
        var result = LineParser().formatSomethingElse(arg1);
        callback(null, result);
    }
], function (err, result) {
    // retrieve the final string
});
```

which can be turned into something useful if you modify your LineParser methods into asynchronous methods (otherwise it will only make your 3 lines heavier)

Comment: While asynchronous programming is a functional style, functional style is not asynchronous programming. It's like claiming vehicles are cars (completely ignoring non-car vehicles like trucks, bicycles, boats and planes).

Comment: @slebetman Ok, but does it make my answer out of the subject ? Feel free to edit text if you think I wrote something not correct

Answer (score -1):

Functional style, that is, pure functional style that we see in Lisp etc. looks like this:

```
var outputline = formatSomethingElse(capitalize(formatSpaces(inputline)));
```

Often, for readability it would be formatted as:

```
var outputline = formatSomethingElse(
    capitalize(
        formatSpaces(inputline)
    )
);
```

Any other form is not functional style. Functional style are a bit like Reverse Polish Notation in that the stated operation should be read in reverse. Indeed, RPN is itself a functional programming syntax (as embodied by Forth).

There is a style that has a similar look and feel to the functional style: method chaining:

```
var outputline = LineParser(inputline)
    .formatSpaces()
    .capitalize()
    .formatSomethingElse()
    .toString();
```

Unlike functional style, method chaining is read in order.

While the most famous chaining library, jQuery, mutates the state of the object it's not really necessary to do that. Take for example the following simple implementation of `LineParser`:

```
function LineParser (text) {
    return {
        text: text,
        toString: function () {return this.text},
        capitalize: function () {
            // return a new object instead of "this"
            return {
                text : _capitalize(this.text),
                toString : this.toString
            }
        }
    }
}
```